# Unable to install spark with sparklyr in Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker, apache-spark, sparklyr

We are trying to build our own docker image to use R and the tidyverse with Spark. However, we are getting an error in the build when trying to install Spark.

Here is our Dockerfile:

```
# start with the most up-to-date tidyverse image as the base image
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest

# install openjdk 8 (Java)
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

# Install sparklyr
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE sparklyr

# Install spark
RUN Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install("2.4.3")'

RUN mv /root/spark /opt/ && \
    chown -R rstudio:rstudio /opt/spark/ && \
    ln -s /opt/spark/ /home/rstudio/

RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE DBI
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE RPostgres
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE dbplyr
```

We are using `Docker compose up` to build and then create the container.

When building, it throws the error:

```
=> ERROR [4/8] RUN Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install("2.3.0")'                                                              62.0s 
------
 > [4/8] RUN Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install("2.3.0")':
#7 61.85 Error in download.file(installInfo$packageRemotePath, destfile = installInfo$packageLocalPath,  :
#7 61.85   download from 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.3.0/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz' failed
#7 61.85 Calls: <Anonymous>
#7 61.85 Execution halted
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install("2.3.0")']: exit code: 1
```

We have also tried running it as:

```
RUN R -e 'sparklyr::spark_install("2.4.3")'
```

Instead of:

```
RUN Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install("2.4.3")'
```

but it stil throws an error. We have also tried installing different versions of Spark to see if that would work but still no luck. Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how I can properly install spark with sparklyr in docker? Thank you.

Comment: can you show your complete Dockerfile, with the base image you are using?

Comment: Frederico Paparoni - It is working now. I went to my list of docker images and deleted the base image off of my dockerhub and then ran the docker compose and it worked. I have no idea why it worked but it did. I added the full dockerfile to the post.

Comment: I found my answer here https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/2936. While sparklyr is trying to install spark, it keeps timing out.

Comment: I continue this discussion with a more specific approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66218303/dockerfile-is-unable-to-install-spark-using-sparklyr