# Sparklyr fails to download Spark from apache in Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to create a dockerfile that builds an image from Rocker/tidyverse and include Spark from sparklyr. Previously, on this post: [Unable to install spark with sparklyr in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144461/unable-to-install-spark-with-sparklyr-in-dockerfile), I was trying to figure out why spark wouldn't download from my dockerfile. After playing with it for the past 5 days I think I have found the reason but have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# start with the most up-to-date tidyverse image as the base image
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest

# install openjdk 8 (Java)
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

# Install devtools
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("devtools")'

# Install sparklyr
RUN Rscript -e 'devtools::install_version("sparklyr", version = "1.5.2", dependencies = TRUE)'

# Install spark
RUN Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install(version = "3.0.0", hadoop_version = "3.2")'

RUN mv /root/spark /opt/ && \
    chown -R rstudio:rstudio /opt/spark/ && \
    ln -s /opt/spark/ /home/rstudio/

RUN apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev --install-suggests
RUN apt-get install odbc-postgresql

RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE DBI
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE RPostgres
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE dbplyr
```

It has no problem downloading everything up until this line:

`RUN Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install(version = "3.0.0", hadoop_version = "3.2")'`

Which then gives me the error:

```
Step 5/11 : RUN Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install(version = "3.0.0", hadoop_version = "3.2")'
 ---> Running in 739775db8f12
Error in download.file(installInfo$packageRemotePath, destfile = installInfo$packageLocalPath,  : 
  download from 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.0.0/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz' failed
Calls: <Anonymous>
Execution halted
ERROR: Service 'rocker_sparklyr' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c Rscript -e 'sparklyr::spark_install(version = "3.0.0", hadoop_version = "3.2")'' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

After doing some research I thought that it was a timeout error, in which case I ran beforehand:

`RUN Rscript -e 'options(timeout=600)'`

This did not increase the time it took to error out again. I installed everything onto my personal machine through Rstudio and it installed with no problems. I think the problem is specific to docker in that it isn't able to download from https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.0.0/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz

I have found very little documentation on this problem and am relying heavily on this post to figure it out. Thank you in advance to anyone with this knowledge for reaching out.

Answer (score 1):

download the version yourself and then use this function to install

```
sparklyr::spark_install_tar(tarfile ="~/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz")
```

Comment: Thank you Stephane, I think that is what I am going to have to do. I was hoping it wouldn't come to that because I was trying to make this docker image as user friendly as possible without having to download the tarfile on their machine, but it seems like the only logical answer.